# When do homotopies have continuous measure?

Tags: measure-theory, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space and $h:X\times[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a homotopy. I am interested in the function $m:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}_+$ given by $t\mapsto\lambda(\textrm{range}(h_t))$. Specifically, under what conditions is $m$ continuous? I have proven that if $X$ is compact, then $m$ is upper-semicontinuous, but have come up with an example with each $h_t$ injective that is not lower semi-continuous. I have proven that if $X$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and each $h_t$ is injective then $m$ is lower-semicontinuous, but have come up with an example with each $h_t$ injective and differentiable that is not upper-semicontinuous. Putting these and differentiable functions preserving measure zero sets together we have that if $X$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\lambda(\partial X)=0$ and each $h_t$ is injective and differentiable, then $m$ is continuous, but that is the best I've been able to do. I suspect that the injectivity condition could be dropped there, but any reasonable condition for continuity would be nice.

EDIT: I’ve realised that if $X$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\lambda(\partial X)=0$ and $h$ is $C^1$ then $m$ is continuous.